# Isomorphic app and browser-specific code

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I am building an isomorphic app with webpack, React, ES6 and fluxible and has run in into a following issue regarding browser-specific modules import.

For example, I want to use imagesloaded in my React component. The code for this looks like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component, findDOMNode } from "react";
import imagesLoaded from "imagesloaded";
```

But, obviously, it tries to do the import on the server-side first, and the code fails miserably with an error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

The question is — what approach should I take so the code is only included for the browser-side version? I guess I am looking for something like:

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
  require("../style/components/Shop.scss");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in exactly same way, that you mentioned, use `require`

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
   require("imagesloaded");
}
```

That will work.
Also there is more options to do it:

1. Provide fake instance of the library for node environment. You can use [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery), for it.
2. Create fake instance of window. AFAIK, [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/) doesn't rely of browser-specific features, only utilizes window as global namespace, so you can make alias for it.

Like this code:

```
global.window = global
```

Comment: I've done it, and now I face a different error: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'eventEmitter/EventEmitter' in /Users/opportunato/projects/grabr-web-client/node_modules/imagesloaded Looks I'll have to create a different error, as it is related more to imagesLoaded as module and not to its use in isomorphic.

Comment: Looks like this library depends from some another lib. Try to import `imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js`. This file has bundled dependencies

Comment: I've opened an issue here, looks there is some error in AMD definition — or I am doing something wrong. https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/203 Thanks!